# OpenTok - Subscriber failed to subscribe to a stream in a reasonable amount of time

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I am implementing a Network Test for my Web-application using OpenTok's js library.

To do that, I create a publisher, connect to session, then make a subscriber connect to the publisher's stream.

The Test is working on other browsers (I have tested Chrome and Internet Explorer) but on Firefox version 57.0.1 I get an error - 'The stream was unable to connect due to a network error. Make sure you have a stable network connection and that it isn't blocked by a firewall.'

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure when you create the OpenTok Session you are using a 'routed' Session, not a 'relayed' one. Also make sure you are passing the 'testNetwork' property to the subscribe method. Here is a working sample:

```
// Sample code
var session = OT.initSession(APIKEY, SESSIONID);

session.connect(TOKEN, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    alert(err.message);
    return;
  }
  var publisher = session.publish();
  publisher.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
    session.subscribe(event.stream, null, {
      testNetwork: true
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) alert(err.message);
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsbin.com/quruzac/edit

Comment: adding the testNetwork property fixed it. Thank you. But it's weird that it worked in Chrome without it.

Comment: If you don't add the testNetwork property then it just displays the same stream again locally without actually streaming it over the network and back again. Not sure why that isn't working in Firefox though, it should do.

Comment: Not sure. Another disparity is Firefox correctly identifies that there is no audio source, but Chrome doesn't detect that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am using the DetectRTC library to check if the user has a microphone attached before making the call. Even when I disable the microphone in my computer, Chrome doesn't throw an error saying that my microphone is disabled as long as my webcam is attached, but rightly tells me that my camera is attached but a microphone is not. Does that make more sense ?